# How to copy file from gitlab runner into docker image through dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, devops, gitlab-ci-runner

I need to be able to copy ssl files that is inside a private gitlab server into the docker image through gitlab ci/cd.

Below is the configuration of my gitlab runner. I have mapped the volume of /root/server-ssl directory so the files could be read through the ci/cd

```
[runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker.myserver.com/gitlab-base-image"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = true
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock",
 "/root/.docker/config.json:/root/.docker/config.json",
 "/cache",
 "/root/server-ssl:/root/server-ssl"]
    extra_hosts = ["gitlab.myserver.com:<some_ip>"]
    shm_size = 0
```

And below is my dockerfile configuration:

```
# 1 - Build environment
FROM node:10.16 as react-build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn
COPY . ./
RUN yarn build

# 2 - Production environment
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN mkdir -p /root/server-ssl
COPY /root/server-ssl/ssl.chained.crt /root/server-ssl/
COPY /root/server-ssl/ssl.key /root/server-ssl/
COPY nginx.staging.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

But i always get the following error by the gitlab ci/cd runner:

```
Step 5/18 : COPY /root/server-ssl/ssl.chained.crt /root/server-ssl/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder528505413/root/server-ssl/ssl.chained.crt: no such file or directory
```

could anyone provide me some help to copy these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files are not in the docker build context. Can think of a couple of ways to bring them into the docker context

- Create symlink in the folder where the Dockerfile is located with the directory where the files are located
- Physically copy the files to the folder where the Dockerfile is located *before* running the docker build command